# Why would Nintendo (or any game developer) compile their final retail game with "debug" symbols enabled?

Tags: debugging, security, nintendo

I read this: https://zelda64.dev/games/mm#why-is-majoras-mask-so-far-behind-ocarina-of-time

> Retail versions of both games are compiled with -O2 -g3. **-g3 is a debugging flag that includes far more debugging information than just -O2**, but also changes how the compiled code looks. -g3 is also more sensitive to the scope in which variables are declared, so it is harder to produce matching code; Ocarina of Time debug is more flexible here. However, retail versions of Ocarina of Time are also compiled with -O2 -g3, so it too will have this problem when that project moves to supporting retail versions.

Why would they have any kind of debugging mode enabled for their final build? Isn't that exclusively for development/testing?

Comment: We've all been there before - bugs and crashes that only occur in release builds but that go away when run in a debug build. This might be for a number of reasons: memory initialization, different CRTs, whatever; point is: it happens. Having a release build with symbols included helps debug this kind of thing. Is that the specific reason why Nintendo did it? Don't know. But it is a reason why it might be done.